# running php on windows azure, wrong php.ini file is referenced

Tags: php, windows, azure

Hi i have a small api done in php which i want hosted on windows azure, i have downloaded the php sdk, and created a project and put my php folder in it, which has the ext folder and my php-cgi.exe, and also a php.ini file. when i do phpinfo(); it shows that the php.ini file referenced is in C:/windows not in my project folder which is in E drive, also the ext folder reference is shown to be c:/php/ext, which is also wrong, how do i make it point to my ini files within the project. please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the config to something like:

```
<application fullPath="%RoleRoot%\approot\Content\Php\php-cgi.exe" arguments="-c %RoleRoot%\approot\Content\Php\php.ini"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the articles available on the Azure PHP website. This is an official Microsoft website that is run by the Interoperability team at Microsoft. They have lots of good info around PHP on Windows Azure.

http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/build-and-deploy-a-windows-azure-php-application

Also, after you have the development environment setup take a look at this tool which allows you to conveniently package any PHP application for Windows Azure:

https://github.com/blobaugh/paz